# Installing pyopencl on Ubuntu as user

Tags: ubuntu, pip, pyopencl

I am trying to install pyopencl (2014.1) on an Ubuntu machine (3.13.0.77, x86_64) as user (no root privileges).
When running

```
pip install —global-option=build_ext —global-option=„-I/opt/sw/cuda/include -L/opt/sw/cuda/lib64“ pyopencl==2014.1
```

the compiler throws

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_SOURCE=1 -DPYGPU_PACKAGE=pyopencl -DPYOPENCL_USE_DEVICE_FISSION=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_CHRONO=1 -DPYGPU_PYOPENCL=1 -DBOOST_MULTI_INDEX_DISABLE_SERIALIZATION=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_DLL=1 -Dboost=pyopenclboost -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -Ibpl-subset/bpl_subset -I/opt/sw/cuda/include -L/opt/sw/cuda/lib64 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/wrapper/wrap_cl.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/wrapper/wrap_cl.o
  In file included from src/wrapper/wrap_cl.cpp:1:0:
  src/wrapper/wrap_cl.hpp:28:19: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
   #include <CL/cl.h>
```

The Cuda version is

> Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.27

When compiling the package via setuptools it actually succeeds but I am unable to import pyopencl. Instead, I get the error:

```
import pyopencl
pyopencl/__init__.py:34: UserWarning: It looks like you are importing PyOpenCL from its source directory. This likely won't work.
warn("It looks like you are importing PyOpenCL from "
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "pyopencl/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  import pyopencl._cl as _cl
ImportError: No module named _cl
```

The warning obviously implies that I am doing something wrong, but how can I import pyopencl from the right directory?

My `siteconf.py` looks like:

```
BOOST_INC_DIR = []
BOOST_LIB_DIR = []
BOOST_COMPILER = 'gcc43'
BOOST_PYTHON_LIBNAME = ['boost_python-py27']
USE_SHIPPED_BOOST = True
CL_TRACE = False
CL_ENABLE_GL = False
CL_ENABLE_DEVICE_FISSION = False
CL_INC_DIR = ['/opt/sw/cuda/include']
CL_LIB_DIR = ['/opt/sw/cuda/lib64']
CL_LIBNAME = ['OpenCL']
CXXFLAGS = []
LDFLAGS = []
```

What I have to do to import pyopencl from the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

The following needs to be set up in order to install pyopencl with pip.

1. Adding path to header files for C and C++

   ```
   export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/path/to/cuda/include
   export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/path/to/cuda/include
   ```
2. Adding path to library files (libOpenCl.so)

   ```
   export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/cuda/lib
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/cuda/lib
   ```
3. Adding path to executables (optional)

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/cuda/bin
   ```

To activate OpenGL interoperations

```
 pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-DHAVE_GL=1" pyopencl
```

Important is, that nvidia.icd is available at /etc/OpenCL/vendors/. OPENCL_VENDOR_PATH does not work with nvidia. Alternatively [Ubuntu ICD Loader](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/libOpenCL.7.html) can be used to specify where to look for nvidia.icd.

Note: Some more info and a pyopencl example at [Repository](https://github.com/Jesse-jApps/gpu-computing).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL headers could be missing if you have not installed them already. On ubuntu you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install opencl-headers
```

The installed headers can then be found in `/usr/include/CL`:

```
# ls -1 /usr/include/CL
cl.h
cl2.hpp
cl_d3d10.h
cl_d3d11.h
cl_dx9_media_sharing.h
cl_egl.h
cl_ext.h
cl_gl.h
cl_gl_ext.h
cl_platform.h
opencl.h
```

I hope it helps.